# prompt option not working with select_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

If there is value in marital_status then prompt should not be displayed but in my case it's displaying. My code is mentioned below. Please help.

```
= select_tag( 'request[marital_status]', 
options_for_select(marital_status_options,
@employee.marital_status.try(:upcase)), prompt: "Select Marital Status", id: 'employee_marital_status', disabled: @request.submitted?)
```

In employee_helper.rb

```
def marital_status_options
  Employee::MaritalStatus::ALL.zip(Employee::MaritalStatus::ALL)
end
```

In employee model

```
module MaritalStatus
  MARRIED = 'MARRIED'
  SINGLE = 'SINGLE'
  DIVORCED = 'DIVORCED'
  ALL = [MARRIED, SINGLE, DIVORCED]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The format and usage is correct. Kindly verify if `@employee.marital_status.try(:upcase)` exactly matches one of the `marital_status_options` provided here.

That looks like a probable case for such a behaviour.

Also, the first argument expected in select_tag needs to in an appropriate format, in this case, an array of strings.

Hence, your method `marital_status_options` should return an array of options to be used for dropdown.

```
def marital_status_options
  ['MARRIED', 'SINGLE', 'DIVORCED']
end
```

Comment: yes, it is matching and marital_status getting updated correctly. promt is also coming but it should not show in a drop-down when there is value in marital_status.

Comment: Modify your `marital_status_options` method to return an array of strings. That should fix the problem. 
`def marital_status_options
  ['MARRIED', 'SINGLE', 'DIVORCED']
end`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19823388)

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb What exactly am I missing. This should solve the issue reported here.

Comment: That was a comment after a review before you edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're very close. The problem here likely stems from your `marital_status_options` method: this will simply return `DIVORCED` as it evaluates to the last line due to your assignment.

Therefore, you might find the value is selected if your instance contains 'DIVORCED', though not either of the other values; your instance's value needs to match one of these for it to be selected instead of the prompt.

You likely want to change this:

```
def marital_status_options
  MARRIED = 'MARRIED' # this will be evaluated first
  SINGLE = 'SINGLE' # then this
  DIVORCED = 'DIVORCED' # finally, this will be evaluated and returned as 'DIVORCED'
end
```

To an array, either:

```
def marital_status_options
  ['MARRIED', 'SINGLE', 'DIVORCED']
end
```

Or, to present the options as lowercase but keep uppercase values in the db:

```
def marital_status_options
  [['Married', 'MARRIED'], ['Single', 'SINGLE'], ['Divorced', 'DIVORCED']]
end
```

Take a look at the docs on [`options_for_select`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select) and you'll see who they can be setup.

Further down the line, you might want to consider switching to [`enums`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) - these are very handy for managing selections such as these, and auto generate methods such as `Employee.married`, `employee.divorced?`, and so forth.

As someone else has mentioned, it's best practice to store data such as this in the relevant model, though I'd argue these should be stored as a constant as they won't be changing. So one of the following:

```
# employee.rb
MARITAL_STATUSES = ['MARRIED', 'SINGLE', 'DIVORCED'].freeze
# or
MARITAL_STATUSES = [['Married', 'MARRIED'], ['Single', 'SINGLE'], ['Divorced', 'DIVORCED']].freeze

= select_tag('request[marital_status]', 
             options_for_select(Employee::MARITAL_STATUSES,
                                @employee.marital_status.try(:upcase)), 
             prompt: "Select Marital Status", 
             id: 'employee_marital_status', 
             disabled: @request.submitted?)
```

Hope that helps - let me know if you've any questions or need anything else.

Comment: Above in question, I have added exact methods which I had in the file please check and let me know if you find anything wrong.

Comment: @ruby.r - that looks like it should work. Have you considered using `:include_blank` instead of `prompt`? I wonder if `prompt` is designed to always show, whereas know for a fact `include_blank` allows for the selection of values. Perhaps try this, replacing `prompt: ...` with `include_blank: ...`?

Answer (score -1):

```
= select_tag "request[marital_status]", options_for_select(Employee.marital_status_options,
@employee.marital_status.try(:upcase)), :include_blank => '--Select Marital Status--', id: id: 'employee_marital_status', disabled: @request.submitted?
```

It's a good practice to define marital_status_options(Business logic) inside model: -

Assuming that it's Employee model

```
def self.marital_status_options
  [
    ["MARRIED","MARRIED"],
    ["SINGLE","SINGLE"],
    ["DIVORCED", "DIVORCED"]
  ]
end
```

Reason that it's not selecting your default marital_status is because if `@employee.marital_status.try(:upcase)` will not match any of the `marital_status_options`, it will show your `prompt` option, so check it carefully that if `@employee.marital_status.try(:upcase)` matches any of the given options of select tag's option.

Comment: Above in question, I have added exact methods which I had in the file please check and let me know if you find anything wrong

Comment: @ruby.r Well I'm not sure why that is not working , could you go ahead with my approach .? probably it will work. So far I guess the selected option value doesn't work with employee.martial_status that's why it doesn't select the selected option.

Comment: @ruby.r is Any updates, is it working? And I don't think answer should be downvoted.